# How to solve App Store libicucore.A.dylib sumission issue

Tags: java, mac-app-store

I got this error when trying to update an application to App Store:

> 2.5
>
> The use of non-public APIs can lead to a poor user experience should
>   these APIs change in the future, and is therefore not permitted. The
>   following non-public APIs are included in your application:
>
> Framework:
>
> '/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib'
>
> Non-public APIS:
>
> : ubrk_getRuleStatus : ubrk_setUText : ucnv_getCanonicalName :
>   ucnv_reset : ucol_strcollIter
>
> If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as
>   the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so
>   that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your
>   application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a
>   library included with your application. If you do not have access to
>   the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary
>   using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the application is built with jdk1.8.0_65. jdk embedded. More exactly the problem comes from libjfxwebkit.dylib library that is importing libicucore.A.dylib library. The problem is solved by deleting libjfxwebkit.dylib. Details [here](http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.ro/2015/10/java-8-update-60-is-causing-apps-that.html).